# how to use boost libs in project (VS2015)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have Visual Studio 2015 and I'm trying to build the sample boost 1.62 link program on the '[Boost Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#pch)' page.   I followed the build steps in order to compile the various binaries, like regex.  These are the steps:

```
c:\boost> bootstrap
c:\boost> .\b2
```

I got multiple errors because 'pyconfig.h' was missing, but I don't need this so I thought it was ok.

I set the 'Additional Libraries Directory' in my test project to c:\boost\libs, but at link time, get:

```
error: cannot open file libboost_regex-vc140-mt-gd-1_62.lib
```

I looked under .\libs and there were no lib files under there.  I did see a new bin.v2 directory under boost\, which, under a very complicate tree has the lib file.

I set the 'Additional Libraries Directories' in my project to c:\boost\bin.v2, but same error.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to be able to link successfully?  Do I need to resolve that pyconfig.h error to get the libs deployed to the right location?

Comment: If you don't want Boost.Python, then you should be able to avoid the pyconfig.h error by passing the `--without-python` argument to `b2`. Boost libs are built under `stage\lib`, so add that to *Additional Libraries Directory* (and make sure the regex lib actually exists under there)

Comment: Thanks!  By bypassing python, I was able to see the build success message that said to add stage\lib to the lib path, as I found out.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It appears VC++ projects should add an include path to  .\boost\stage\lib, instead of what the boost webpage says.  I don't know if this is true intention, but it appears to work.